# Mapping of Exchange error codes to SMTP status codes

Tags: email, exchange, email-server

Exchange error codes use a dotted notation x.y.z, for example 4.3.1 is an "Insufficient system resources" message. Is there a 1:1 mapping between this and SMTP error codes without dots (431) and if so what was the reason for using the different format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3 digit error codes come from the original SMTP specification [RFC 821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821#page-36).

The dot separated error codes are [RFC 3463 compliant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3463#section-2) which was drafted because those SMTP error codes were deemed insufficient:

> There is a need for a standard mechanism for the reporting of mail
> system errors richer than the limited set offered by SMTP and the
> system specific text descriptions sent in mail messages.
> ...

Comment: Thanks very much for the prompt reply - much appreciated!